# Using Amazon S3 bucket or Cloudfront for storing product images - Magento

Tags: amazon-web-services, magento, amazon-s3, storage, amazon-cloudfront

I am setting up a big ecommerce website having a million products onto Magento CE 1.9.3.4 (each product having 3-4 images on average)

**My purpose** is to ease mp VPS file system load by putting my /media/ folder onto S3 bucket. I have achieved this using this extension. https://github.com/thaiphan/magento-s3/

**Problem**
If the media files are not found on S3 (usually cache or may be some other), the request should be sent to Magento web server. But its not happening. Am i missing something in S3 configuration or in above extension?

I had also tried S3FS-FUSE, with this extension also, i faced the same problem with RSYNC. Due to slow rsync & amazon CLI even, it takes time to sync cache images.

**Probable alternative i found but i don't understand:-**
http://inchoo.net/magento/set-up-cdn-in-magento/

**I just want to ask two simple queries:-**
1) Am i missing any configuration to resolve this cache images issue? or any troubleshooting guidance will be really helpful

2) Do you think, using above alternative (cloudfront) will solve my purpose of easing the VPS load for images? Because what i know about cloudfront is, it is helpful for global websites, (my website is country specific, so going for S3)

Comment: Did you add the URL (and the dir) of cloudfront in the magento configuration ?

Comment: *"Because what i know about cloudfront is, it is helpful for global websites, (my website is country specific, so going for S3)"*  This certainly isn't a reason not to use CloudFront for a site that does not have a global audience.  *"It is actually limitation of S3 as magento product using cache images. But my product page shows broken links of images as cache images are available/sync at S3 instantly as generated by Magento."*  Can you rephrase this to clarify?  The nature of the problem is not clear from this description.

Comment: @kintuparantu - as of now i am not using cloudfront.. only s3 and its subdomain url is updated in magento admin

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - Problem is:- If the media files are not found on S3 (usually cache or may be some other), the request should be sent to Magento web server. But its not happening. Am i missing something in S3 configuration or in above extension?